# Show that atom of Boolean algebra B inside B' is also the atom of B' where B' is subalgebra of B.

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters, boolean-ring

Let B := (B, ≤, ∨, ∧,
c
, 0, 1) be a Boolean algebra and B'
:= (B'
, ≤, ∨, ∧,
c
, 0, 1) be
a Boolean subalgebra of B. Show that an element of B0
that is an atom of B must also
be an atom of B'
. However, there can be atoms of B'
that are not atoms of B.

I know some basic concept of atoms and its existence that for an atom a of BA B ... please guide me in steps...

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is an atom in $B$, then there's no smaller nonzero element in $B$, so neither can such exist in $B'$.

For the other direction, consider e.g. a subalgebra of the Boolean algebra $P(\{1,2,3,4\})$.